# How to do an action only when there is no default in JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm asked that a click anywhere in a div does a specific action (say collapse it) *unless* the click was on a link, a button, etc...

Basically, I'd like the reverse of `event.preventDefault()`.

Is there a good and easy way to do this?

I'm looking for a *generic* solution here; I would like to not assume much about the content of the div.

Might look like:

```
<div id="click_me>
<p>Clicking here should do stuff
   <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">but not here, nor on the following image</a>
   <a href="/xyz"><img url="/icon.png"/></a>
   imagine buttons... input areas, ...
</p>
</div>
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
$("#click_me").click(function(){
  if(black_magic) {
    $("#click_me").toggleClass("collapsed");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to make sure the event `target` is not a link nor a button.

```
$('#click_me').click(function(e) {
  interactive = 'a, button, input, textarea, video, map, object';
  if($(event.target).closest(interactive).length == 0) ) {
    $("#click_me").toggleClass("collapsed");
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, for example if the click is on an image inside an `a`

Comment: Getting closer! I edited your answer to make it more complete. Still, I still wish there was an easier way, and one that didn't force me to stop bubbling if I want to attach event handlers to some nested divs. Maybe someone else can come up with a better answer.

Comment: instead of interactive="a,button,input" etc, why not just use .closest('.keepDefault') and add that class to every element that needs to do the default behavior?

Comment: @resopollution: I feel it's not the responsability of the content that the container behaves in a certain way. The container can be very generic, like a piece of GUI that can be used in many places on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this handler to your link:

```
$("#click_me a,button,input,textarea,video,map,object").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

To prevent the event to get to the div (bubble up). It will stop so the link will behave correctly.

[**See it in action.**](http://jsbin.com/areju3/3/edit) (click preview)

Comment: Gorgeous preview! What about stuff inside `a`, for instance?

Comment: Stuff inside <a> "bubbles up" all the way to <a>, so if a span inside <a> gets clicked, <a> also gets clicked, but e.stopPropagation() prevents further bubbling up, so in this case your div outside of <a> will not collapse.  

If you don't want <a> to be clicked if something inside <a> like a <span> is clicked, you can bind a click handler to the <span> tag inside <a> and do e.stopPropagation to stop the bubbling.

Comment: @galambalaz: First time on jsbin, very nice. No cynicism at all. Indeed, that works well even for embedded stuff. I've modified it to allow for buttons, etc...

Answer (score 1):

`Event bubbling` is the keyword here. Bind an event handler to the div and check the `event target` to specify what to do.

```
$('div.mydivclass').bind('click', function(event){
    switch(event.target.id){
        case 'id_of_an_anchor':{
              alert('anchor was clicked');
              break;
        }
        case 'id_of_a_span':{
              alert('span was clicked');
              break;
        }
        default: {
              alert('something else was clicked within me');
        }
    }
});
```

Of course you can even check for the targets `tagName` or `nodeType`.

Comment: What if the target is inside an `a`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onClick(e){
    var gates = "A,INPUT,TEXTAREA,SELECT";
    var bound = this;
    var isCollapse = function ( node ){ 
    if( node == bound ){ return true; }
        var re = new RegExp( "\\b" +node.nodeName+ "\\b", "g" );
        return re.test( gates ) ? false : isCollapse( node.parentNode );
    };

    if( isCollapse( event.srcElement || e.target ) ){
        alert( "collapse" )
        // collapse()
    }
}
document.getElementById("click_me").onclick = onClick;
```

***fixed ***  for cases like: `<a href="_"><span><strike> a link </strike></span></a>`

Comment: I prefer the style of the other solutions, plus I think it won't work when clicking on me: `<select>Pick <b>me</b></select>`, for example.